# Do something by clicking on an element of a v-for of Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like that when I click on a specific element of the v-for I will be given feedback within that same element.
My problem is that to do this I inserted a @click inside the element with a method that has an additional AddEventLister inside.
This causes a problem, the feedback is given to me only on the second click on the element.

```
This is Vue code

<i @click="addToCart(dish), getFeedback(dish);" class="fa-solid fa-plus d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-3"></i>
<span class="alert alert-primary d-none">
Hai aggiunto il piatto al carrello
</span>
```

```
This is the method


getFeedback(){

          const addDish = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-plus');
          const alert = document.querySelectorAll('.alert');        

          // PARTE AL SECONDO CLICK
          for(let i = 0; i < addDish.length; i++){
            
            addDish[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                alert[i].classList.remove('d-none');  
                addDish[i].classList.remove('d-flex');
                addDish[i].classList.add('d-none');
                setTimeout(function(){
                  alert[i].classList.add('d-none');
                  addDish[i].classList.add('d-flex');
                  addDish[i].classList.remove('d-none');
              },2000);
              })
          }
        },
```

Comment: The case here is that You should contain function `addToCart()` and `getFeedback()` into one function like `handleClick(dish)` and then inside this function operate on the 2 others. Also why are You assigning handlers to @click event but also listening on `addEventListener(....)`?  `@click` is for that, but moreover you're supposed to use `ref="...."` in Vue instead of raw eventListeners as they can make a lot of headaches.  
Ex: https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-vue-refs/

Answer (score 0):

The first click runs the for loop and adds a new event listener.  That event listener will not run on the same click you add it!  The click has already happened, and adding the new listener is the **result** of the first click.  The second click will then run the event listener added by the first click which then runs your additonal code. There doesn't seem to be a good reason to have that additional event listener.  To fix your code all you should need to do is remove the `addDish[i].addEventListener` line (and it's closing bracket)

```js
for(let i = 0; i < addDish.length; i++){
                alert[i].classList.remove('d-none');  
                addDish[i].classList.remove('d-flex');
                addDish[i].classList.add('d-none');
                setTimeout(function(){
                  alert[i].classList.add('d-none');
                  addDish[i].classList.add('d-flex');
                  addDish[i].classList.remove('d-none');
              },2000);
          }
```

However, I have to state this entire strategy isn't a very Vue-like solution.  There are very few reasons with Vue to directly query/manipulate the DOM.  If you're doing it a lot, it's probably a sign that you're not leveraging the power of Vue correctly.  For example with your code a simple boolean flag with [conditional rendering](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html) using `v-if` and `v-else` could replace all your DOM code.  See my example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-lake-cs06e3?file=/src/App.vue) for what I mean.

Comment: Using the code you recommended, the result is that feedback is assigned to all elements of the loop and not just to the one clicked.
How can I fix this? About of the power of Vue, how would you use a v-if v-else in this case?

Comment: the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-lake-cs06e3?file=/src/App.vue) I linked shows exactly how to do this with Vue